# Excel VBA finding a text and return row number (loop)

Tags: excel, vba, loops, find, row

I am finding a difficulty in probably a rather simple code to return the corresponding row numbers which contain a specific text in column("A:A"). Have been trying several ways but without success - it does not loop through the last row.
Here is what I have got so far:

```
Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim FindRow As Variant
Dim RowN As Integer
Dim blockSize As Integer

rowCount = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
 
For i = 2 To rowCount 
    
    Set FindRow = Cells(i, 1).Find(What:="group: 1", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
    RowN = FindRow.Row
    MsgBox RowN

    If RowN > 1 Then
    blockSize = FindRow.Row - 1
    MsgBox blockSize
    End If

Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Find` is only searching one cell in the region.  Using that method you should use `Instr` to check each cell.

The `Find` method will find the first occurrence in a range, and `FindNext` will find subsequent occurrences.

```
Option Explicit
    
Sub Test()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim srchRange As Range
        Set srchRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow, 1))
    End With
    
    With srchRange
        Dim rFound As Range
        Set rFound = .Find("group: 1", .Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlPart, , xlNext, False)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            Dim firstAdd As String
            firstAdd = rFound.Address
            
            Dim FoundRows As String
            Dim blocksize As Long
                
            Do
                If rFound.Row > 1 Then
                    blocksize = rFound.Row - 1
                    'other code.
                    
                End If
                Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
            Loop Until rFound.Address = firstAdd
        
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

If you wanted to add more flexibility to the process you could rewrite it as a function so you can search different groups, different columns and different sheets.

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim Result As Variant
    Result = GetBlocks(, , ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"))
    
    If IsEmpty(Result) Then
        MsgBox "No groups found."
    Else
        Dim itm As Variant
        For Each itm In Result
            MsgBox itm
        Next itm
    End If

End Sub

Function GetBlocks(Optional GroupID As String = "group: 1", _
                   Optional ColNum As Long = 1, _
                   Optional wrkSht As Worksheet) As Variant
                   
    'Optional arguments must be constant expressions, so a
    'default worksheet can't be set before here.
    If wrkSht Is Nothing Then Set wrkSht = ActiveSheet

    'Define the range to be searched.
    With wrkSht
        Dim lastrow As Long
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColNum).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim srchRange As Range
        Set srchRange = .Range(.Cells(1, ColNum), .Cells(lastrow, ColNum))
    End With
    
    With srchRange
        Dim rFound As Range
        Set rFound = .Find(GroupID, .Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlPart, , xlNext, False)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            Dim firstAdd As String
            firstAdd = rFound.Address
            
            'Create a string of row numbers.
            'e.g. 4,6,8,11,13,14,16,17, < note final comma.
            Dim FoundRows As String
            Do
                If rFound.Row > 1 Then
                    FoundRows = FoundRows & rFound.Row & ","
                End If
                Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
            Loop Until rFound.Address = firstAdd
            
            'Split string into arrow of row numbers.
            'These will be string data types.
            Dim tmp As Variant
            tmp = Split(FoundRows, ",")
            
            'Convert string to long data type.
            ReDim tmp1(0 To UBound(tmp) - 1)
            Dim x As Long
            For x = 0 To UBound(tmp1)
                tmp1(x) = CLng(tmp(x))
            Next x
            
            'Return result of function.
            GetBlocks = tmp1
            
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Since the parameter for `SearchOrder` is omitted, you could also omit the parameters for `After` (`.Cells(1, 1)`), `SearchDirection` (`xlNext`) and `MatchCase` (`False`), since they are the default values. Keep in mind that the `LookIn` parameter `xlValues` will cause the `Find` method to fail finding the value in hidden rows (easily tested), therefore `xlFormulas` is mostly preferred.

Comment: Thank you for your advice - very helpful! It does work perfectly to obtain the row numbers. However,  I need to use the row number as an integer for following set of commands (one written above "blockSize = FindRow.Row - 1"). Is there anyway that I can get the row number as an integer value?

Comment: Have updated the code so it shows the row number each time.  Not sure of your final definition of a block size - just the row number before the keyword is found?